# Linux CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO: What specific folders/files must be in the source tree for this feature to function?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

In my build of Linux kernel 2.6.35.14 for an embedded system, I would like to use the CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO feature. The build process only includes any modified files in the local build tree (version controlled) and sources the remainder from our Vendor's source tree (not version controlled).

What specific files/folders need to be local for the feature to function?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `scripts/setlocalversion` which is used to get the version from the SCM (it can be  git, mercurial or svn).

You can probably modify that script to your needs.